# How can I define custom validator in CKAN 2.2

Tags: python, validation, ckan

I need to define a new validator for dates in my extension for CKAN 2.2. IValidators interface is not working. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are currently [three different function prototypes](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/adding-custom-fields.html#custom-validators) available for a custom validator.  Here's an example of a custom date string validator using the prototype that takes two parameters (option 5 in the documentation link).  This type must return the final value of the field (conversely, it has the ability to alter the value before it is stored):

```
import ckan.plugins as plugins
import ckan.plugins.toolkit as tk  
from ckan.plugins.toolkit import Invalid

def date_str_validator(value, context):
    valid_date = tk.get_validator('isodate')(value, context)
    if not valid_date or not isinstance(valid_date, datetime.datetime):
        raise Invalid("Invalid date")
    return value

class MyPlugin(plugins.SingletonPlugin, tk.DefaultDatasetForm):

    plugins.implements(plugins.IDatasetForm, inherit=False)

    def _modify_package_schema(self, schema):
        schema.update({
            # Custom extras
            'origination_date':[tk.get_validator('ignore_missing'),
                                date_str_validator,
                                tk.get_converter('convert_to_extras')]
        })
        return schema

    def create_package_schema(self):
        schema = super(MyPlugin, self).create_package_schema()
        schema = self._modify_package_schema(schema)

        return schema

    def update_package_schema(self):
        schema = super(MyPlugin, self).update_package_schema()
        schema = self._modify_package_schema(schema)
        return schema

    def show_package_schema(self):
        schema = super(MyPlugin, self).show_package_schema()

        schema.update({
            # Custom extras
            'origination_date':[tk.get_converter('convert_from_extras'),
                                tk.get_validator('ignore_missing'),
                                date_str_validator]
        })

        return schema
```

Note that validators and converters are called in order, so the order show here is important in both `_modify_package_schema` and `show_package_schema`.

Comment: Does the order of validators affect the order of which validation errors are displayed on form submit? From my experience, it seems not. I'm trying to figure out how to get validation errors to appear in the same order as the fields that display on the page (which are a mix of custom and default fields).